# Outputting a variable value in a textbox with the italics style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I was just wondering how you would go about outputting a variable in a textbox with the italics style?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what you have tried already ?

Comment: No way, unless you implement custom textbox.

Comment: Yes, i have tried things but have not worked and how would i make a custom textbox?

Answer (score 0):

add a class with font-style

```
.inputBox {
font-style: italic;
}

  <input type="text" class="inputBox"/>
```

Comment: Im outputting multiple variables as im making a referencing generator. The user will be inputting the data, i was just wondering how to make the title output in italics?

Comment: css tooltip would help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myTxt"/>
```

JQuery:

```
var a = "Some value";
$('#myTxt').val(a);
$('#myTxt').css("font-style","italic");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n5nfLqv9/)

updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5nfLqv9/10/)

Comment: how can do i do that but for a specific value?

Comment: If i want to display a + b with a press of a button. How could i output a in italics and b as bold?

Comment: You used div in your example and your question says textbox

Comment: this is my fiddle. What is actually your problem with my fiddle?

Comment: Basically want one variable to be outputted in italics and one variable to outputted in normal font...

Comment: is there another alternative?